# iPhone vs. iPad Apps

Tags: ios, design, ipad

I am trying to create an iPad app using the existing iPhone app design. I would like to know what kind of differences should I introduce in the app design as to suit it for the bigger iPad screen.

I started designing the iPhone app 'coz I thought it would be easier to design one and will easily be able to port it to iPad. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad screen is about 4 times the pixel size, and 9 times the physical size of that on the iPhone. This is such huge difference that you can't just scale up and be done with it.

You'll have to rethink how you layout text to keep your line-length [within reason](http://www.humanfactors.com/downloads/nov02.asp).

There is so much more real-estate you can have some actual navigation in the main layout.

Compare for instance [Reeder for the iPhone](http://reederapp.com/iphone/index) and the [same app for the iPad](http://reederapp.com/ipad/).

Or [Flipboard](http://flipboard.com) on [different devices](http://likertise.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/nexus-7-review/):
[image]

The really short answer: everything (except perhaps visual style) should be different if the screen becomes 4 times bigger.

Answer (score 1):

[There's a good step by step guide here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad) where one can follow an example iPhone app being ported to iPad. It brings up some of the features/controls suitable for the generous screen space of the iPad and which controls it can substitute on the iPhone.